# How to check the column types of all partitions/shards in a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, sqldatatypes, partition

I've been asked to help out a project with some issues.

The first one is that they've created a sharded/partitioned table, is one shard/partition per week of data.  The thing is, it ***appears*** that sometimes the `Date` column is a STRING and sometimes it's a TIMESTAMP *(I wish they wouldn't use datatype names for column names)*

I've discovered this with the following query...

```
SELECT Date FROM `foor.bar.tableName_*` GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date
```

Which gives the error...

```
Cannot read field 'Date' of type STRING as TIMESTAMP_MICROS
```

How do I easily identify which shards/partitions have which datatypes in that column?

How do I easily correct this?

Do I have the correct terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this isn't actually a partitioned table. If you use a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), you have a single table with a consistent schema across all partitions, whereas if you use multiple tables that share a common prefix and suffix pattern, there is no such guarantee. I would strongly suggest converting the existing tables into a partitioned table if you can.

For the sake of finding incompatible types across tables, [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063) will make it easier to analyze multiple tables at once, but for now, here is one approach to find incompatibilities, assuming you're using e.g. a Bash terminal:

```
DATASET=<dataset name here>
COLUMN_NAME=<column name here>
for table_name in `bq ls -n 1000 $DATASET | tail -n +3 | grep -Eo "t[^ ]+"`; do
  bq --format=json show $DATASET.$table_name | \
    sed -r "s/.*\{([^\{]*\"name\":\"$COLUMN_NAME\"[^\}]*)\}.*/\1/g" | \
    sed -r 's/.*\"type\":\"([^\"]+)\".*/\1/g' | \
    xargs echo $table_name | \
    sort;
done
```

This gives output like,

```
tableName20180101 STRING
tableName20180102 STRING
tableName20180103 TIMESTAMP
...
```